# SQL Server and DBase IV

Tags: sql-server, delphi, delphi-xe2, advantage-database-server, dbase

Presently, I have an accounting software we bought that use a dBase IV database. The application I have created with Delphi communicates with these database with SAP advantage SQL Server. The advantage is the fact that SAP Advantage has component for Delphi and its quite easy to setup the connection between my application and the dBase file.

Now the bad news is the fact that SAP has decided to discontinue that software and the last version supports Windows Server 2012. In a near future, we want to change the server to Windows Server 2016, but since SAP Advantage doesn't support 2016, I have to find a new way to communicate between my software and the dBase file.

In my search on the web, I think that MS SQL Server can make the connection between dBase and my application but the information and step to do it is really hard to find and I got the feeling I'm running in circles.

Is there someone that can tell me the step to make it work, if it's possible or is there other RDBMS that can work with dBase IV?

Also, I'm open to other way to do it. I think I saw somebody talking about web service. Would it be a good alternative in my case but is I possible to do SQL request with that?

Presently, I'm using SAP Advantage V11, Windows Server 2012 Essential and Delphi XE2.

Thanks for your help

Comment: How do you know SAP has decided to discontinue it? And what makes you think that the same version that runs on Server 2012 won't work on Server 2016?

Comment: As long as you have the proper ODBC or OLE/DB drivers installed you should be able to create a linked server in SQL Server to your DBase database.

Comment: Most of the time, when something is "discontinued", it does *not* necessarily mean it will stop working. It typically just means they will no longer support it.

Comment: FWIW, I have software designed for Windows '95 which runs just fine on Windows 10.

Comment: About a year ago, SAP call me to talk about this discontinues software. Also, they dont have anything that can replace directly this product, especially the part concerning DBase communication.

Comment: Concerning using the software on WS2016, i did not try it but i know that SAP did not indicate compatibility with it. The only thing that im wondering is since my application communicate with the account management software database, i did not want to risk bugging the other software database if the SAP software start bugging on WS2016. That is something i did not know if i should take the risk or the chance,

Comment: Jason, do you have some step by step guide for installing ODBC or OLE/DB because its not quite documented. Right now, i install the MS SQL server on Windows Server 2016 but when i try to make a link server, there is no "Microsoft Jet 4.0" provider in the list. I also install VFPOLEDB provider but it does not appear in the listing. What i found right now is some problem concerning the 32-bit provider not working with the 64-bit MS SQL and there is no provider to my knowledge with 64-bit driver.

Comment: Also, on the devzone, they talk about version 12 but is not available in the download section. He is suppose to check the availability of this version. Also, Ken, did you install version 11 on a Windows Server 2016 by any chance?